# Fix duplicate index names in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am looking for the simplest solution to create a Python data frame from a CSV file that has duplicate index names (s1 and s2 in the example below).

Here is how the CSV file looks like:

```
       var1   var2    var3
unit x    8      4      12
temp y   -1     -4      -3
time     
s1        9     12      11
s2       12     15       7
month    
s1        1      3      12 
s2        2      4       6
```

Python data frame should be as follows:

```
        var1   var2    var3
unit x     8      4      12
temp y    -1     -4      -3
time s1    9     12      11
time s2   12     15       7
month s1   1      3      12
month s2   2      4       6
```

What's the best way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert index to Series
s = df.index.to_series()
#identify duplicated values
m = s.duplicated(keep=False)
#replace dupes by NaNs and then by forward filling
df.index = np.where(m, s.mask(m).ffill() + ' ' + s.index, s)
#remove only NaNs rows
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print (df)
          var1  var2  var3
unit x     8.0   4.0  12.0
temp y    -1.0  -4.0  -3.0
time s1    9.0  12.0  11.0
time s2   12.0  15.0   7.0
month s1   1.0   3.0  12.0
month s2   2.0   4.0   6.0
```

Comment: This line is giving the warning below:
df.index = np.where(m, s.mask(m).ffill() + ' ' + s.index, s)


FutureWarning: using '+' to provide set union with Indexes is deprecated, use '|' or .union()

Is there a way to rewrite it using union() or '|'?

Comment: @arqchicago how working `df.index = np.where(m, s.mask(m).ffill() + ' ' + s, s)`?

Answer (score 0):

considered dataframe

```
        C   D   E
A   B           
a   4   7.0 1.0 5.0
5   3.0 4.0 5.5
b   5   8.0 3.0 3.0
c   4   9.0 5.0 6.0
f   4   3.0 0.0 4.0
```

you can use `df.reset_index` drop is False which can make number of columns based on index levels then you can assign to main index once it is converted

```
#converting index to columns
df = df1.reset_index()
# Assigning multilevel index columns to main index
df.index = df[df.columns[0]].astype(str)+' '+df[df.columns[1]].astype(str)
# dropping the indexed columns
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]],axis=1)
```

Out:

```
    C   D   E
a 4 7.0 1.0 5.0
a 5 3.0 4.0 5.5
b 5 8.0 3.0 3.0
c 4 9.0 5.0 6.0
f 4 3.0 0.0 4.0
```